# custom push alert sound can't update?

Tags: ios, xcode, push, apple-push-notifications

i made a custom push alert sound file, which name is aa.caf (old sound file)

and i import the file in xcode and build it.

provider send a push to iphone, it rings the custom file. wow~!

later, i want to change the sound.

so i make a new sound file.

delete aa.caf file from xcode , put the new one. and i give a name that file to aa.caf (new sound file).

provider sends a push to the phone again,

but the phone doesn't play my new sound file.

it plays old version's sound! no~~!!

i remove the app, and reinstall.

then it rings the new sound file, perfect.

but if the phone has the old version(has old version sound),

and update new app(has new version sound), it won't ring the new sound.

and i don't know why :(

why is that??

and is there a way to solve this problem?

my app is saled on App Store, so i must update that sound

without users delete previous version's app.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? maybe you can answer your own question. I was thinking that maybe you should try to "clean" before you "build and run" again.

Comment: not yet. i send a mail to apple technical support team. they reply me, i'll write the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the answer from apple.

'This bug only involves installation via the Xcode debugger'

and

'To speed up development,
Xcode tries to minimize the amount of data it needs to push to the device on
each build, and sometimes that process misses resources that have changed'